# Combine ActionbarSherlock and Facebook API Graph

Tags: android, facebook, actionbarsherlock

this might be a bit of a newbie question, but here goes: I am currently working on an Android application in which I need the Facebook library and the Action Bar Support library.

when I tried to combine the ABS library (e.g. compile a project into a library) and the Facebook library (e.g. integrate the Facebook SDK for Android as a project and compile it into a library), then I am running into the following problem: the 2 support libraries used by ABS and Facebook are different. When I tried to replace the support librarie in Facebook with the newer one used by ABS, I got into compile errors in the Facebook SDK. So what is the best way to go? How can I combine the both without having to sacrifice support library functionalities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the support librairy in one of them and replace it with the version of the other one.

If you use maven, just remove the library in ABS libs folder, and change the version in the pom to match the support library used by facebook.

Comment: Ok, I found out that I had to do the following (include it in your answer and you can get points ^^): 1. check which support lib is the largest and the newest, 2. replace the older one :), 3. do a cleanup in eclipse, 4. run it :)

Comment: Sure you try to keep the most up to date. But that's not the only constraint as one of the libs may not compile with one version or the other. But usually, support is backward compatible so yes, I guess the newest here is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar difficulty, although, mine was for ABS and the ViewPager library. What I did in my case was:

1. Delete the Support Library `jar` file from *ViewPager*.
2. Added *ABS* as the reference library to the *ViewPager* library
3. In my project, I only reference the *ViewPager*.

In your case, you could try doing this:

1. Delete the Support Library `jar` from the *Facebook SDK*.
2. Add *ABS* as the reference library to the *Facebook SDK*.
3. And in your application project, add the *Facebook SDK* as the only referenced library.

Comment: Thanks, I took the path of Snicolas, but since I like the idea/concept, I do want to give you a point for it :)

Comment: @Jeroen: Lol... Thanks. But I am not really here for rep points. SO is pretty much responsible for teaching me Android. Just playing my part. ;-)

Comment: that's a nice way to go. Yes, I learned a lot from SO as well, might as well starting to contribute a bit more:).